# How do I blend texture over other texture in unity shadergraph but only on the shadow side?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am currently making a game based around colonizing planets, and I would like to know how I overlap a lightmap texture of the earth on a sphere, but only at the positions which are affected by shadow in shadergraph.
I am using **unity 2020.1.0a25** with the **universal render pipeline**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of light across a sphere is at its most basic level determined by the dot product between the surface normal and the vector towards the light. This is called lambert shading. In shader language, it would be written like this:

```
float NdotL = dot(normal, lightDir);
```

We can incorporate this into a custom function in a similar way. Create a custom funciton with two input variables called Normal and WorldPos, and an output variable called Shadow. Paste this code into it:

```
#if SHADERGRAPH_PREVIEW
Shadow = 1 - saturate(dot(float3(0.707, 0.707, 0), Normal));
#else
Light mainLight = GetMainLight();
float lightAmount = saturate(dot(mainLight.direction, Normal));

#ifdef _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS
    uint pixelLightCount = GetAdditionalLightsCount();
    for (uint lightIndex = 0u; lightIndex < pixelLightCount; ++lightIndex)
    {
        Light light = GetAdditionalLight(lightIndex, WorldPos);
        lightAmount += saturate(dot(light.direction, Normal));
}
#endif
Shadow = saturate(1 - lightAmount);
#endif
```

What this function does is that it sums up the light contribution from the main light and all additional lights and returns the inverse of that. Because the dot product produces a value between -1 and 1, it is first clamped to the [0, 1] range using saturate().

Note - what you get out of this function is essentially a gradient that goes from 0 at the terminus to 1 at the point opposite to the sun. You might want to remap this value somehow to have a more sharp border, you can for instance multiply it by 100 and clamp it to [0, 1], or use a square root.

Comment: So I think it should propably work but now I get all these errors [Errors](https://i.imgur.com/SKXoijT.png)

Comment: Add a semicolon after "Shadow = 1". That should fix it.

Comment: The semicolon fixed the errors thanks. But I tried using the shadow output like this: [shader](https://imgur.com/rTQn0Nm) to make emmission but now it puts the emmission everywhere independent of the shadow [earth](https://imgur.com/2HsrkqT) _sorry for my questions but I just started using shadergraph and sorry for my english too, Im still learning it_

Comment: Can you show me the rest of the graph? The function above only works for the main directional light, so maybe that is the issue (if you are using a point light)?

Comment: I am using a point light but I also tried it with a directional light and it worked just like with the point light. Heres the rest of of the graph:[shader](https://i.imgur.com/3II9fVz.png)

Comment: I just realized, my solution was all wrong. It returned the shadow map value of the pixel, but this only gives you shadows cast by objects between the light source and the surface... it doesn't give you the shadow on the opposite side of the sphere. I updated my answer with a better solution. It should also support all light types.